# Digraph Problem...

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

I have been trying to randomly assign colors to various arcs of this graph, but I am not able to arrive at a synchronized coloring. Any hints/suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please remind us what a synchronised colouring is?

Answer (score 1):

Would be nice if I weren't on a phone but here goes. Two left edges label $a$, two right most $b$, top $b$, bottom $a$, $[x,v]$ label $b$ and finally $[v,x]$ labeled $a$. Then the word $abab$ terminates at $v$, $aba$ terminates at $x$, $aabb$ at $w$, and $bbaa$ at $u$.

Comment: Could you please explain the rationale behind the coloring you chose?

Comment: The real trick here is the cycles on the left and right behaving in a controlled manner coupled with the remaining two pairs of labelings have both $b$'s terminating at the same vertex and the $a$'s terminating at the other.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible because of the road coloring theorem.

here is a possible coloring:

[image]

As you can see blue,blue,blue,red always ends in $X$, from here it is easy to find sequences for the other vertices.